# Project Euler #4: Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm having trouble figuring out why my code won't work. Essentially I'm trying to code Project Euler #4, which seeks to figure out the biggest palindrome number that can be obtained from multiplying two three-digit numbers. This code doesn't seem to be working (it'll compile). Whenever I execute the code, it just prints "0". I know it might not be algorithmically efficient, but what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Palindrome {
public static void main (String [] args) {

   int largestnum = 0; 
   Palindrome pp = new Palindrome();

   for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
       for (int k = 100; k <= 999; k++) {
            if (pp.checkPal(i * k) == true) {
                largestnum = i * k;
            }
        }
    }        

   System.out.println(largestnum);
}


public boolean checkPal(int y) {
    String snum = Integer.toString(y);
    int snum_length = snum.length() - 1;
    String palindrome = new String("");

    for (int i = snum_length; i >= 0; i--) {
        palindrome.concat(Character.toString(snum.charAt(i)));
    }

    if (snum.equals(palindrome)) {
        return true;
    }  
    else {
        return false;
    }      
}
}
```

Comment: Lean to use a debugger, it'll save you many hours in the long run.

Comment: You do have a `println` statement in your for loop.

Comment: Oh shoot. Just realized that. Thanks.

Comment: @BoristheSpider months over a career. +1

Comment: One issue is that you never actually check if the current palindrome found is bigger than the value in `largestnum`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider cool advice. doesn't answer my question, though.

Comment: @AntonH well I just assume that as the for loops executes, if a larger palindrome comes up, it'll just replace the old one. Is this flawed?

Comment: @priya yes. Yes it does.  Q:"_what am I doing wrong?_" , A: use a debugger and find out for yourself.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Of course it doesn't. I'm looking for flaws in my code. Not general advice about what I should learn.

Comment: @priya Larger or smaller, so you could potentially be replacing a larger palindrome with a smaller one, since there no comparaison of size/value.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Do you go around commenting on everyone's questions "learn to use a debugger"?

Comment: @AntonH ah, alright. Is this why it simply prints '0'?

Comment: When you use a debugger, your question is "this specific line of code isn't doing what I think it is. Why?". When you don't your question is "This code doesn't work. Why?". We look for questions of the former sort on this site, not the latter.

Comment: @priya Probably not. It's because your `checkPal` is always returning false. Check out Erwin's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Java are immutable.

You are doing:

```
palindrome.concat(Character.toString(snum.charAt(i)));
```

This is an expression that returns a new string that is the concatenation of `palindrome` and `Character.toString(snum.charAt(i))`. It does *not* modify `palindrome`.

You can fix it like this:

```
palindrome = palindrome.concat(Character.toString(snum.charAt(i)));
```

Although it would be better to use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to build up Strings.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting those blank spaces because you have a print statement inside the checkPal function.

Also, when you do `palindrome.concat` you need to assign palindrome to the result like so:
`palindrome = palindrome.concat(Character.toString(snum.charAt(i)));`

Comment: Ahhh, yes. This works, but I think I lack a comparison to find the largest palindrome. Thank you.